# Angular 2 external lib error

Tags: javascript, angular, lib

I generate my angular 2 lib with [yeoman generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) and added to main angular project. If i compile app in dev mode i haven't error, but if i run prod mode, i get many errors:

```
WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/services/main/main.component.ngfactory.ts
142:86-92 "export 'ɵb' (imported as 'i15') was not found in 'ngx-tel-input'
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:65:15)
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:39:15)
at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:24)
at Compilation.finish (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:9)
at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
at /Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:271:11
at _addModuleChain (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/services/main/main.component.ngfactory.ts
144:12-18 "export 'ɵb' (imported as 'i15') was not found in 'ngx-tel-input'
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:65:15)
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:39:15)
at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:24)
at Compilation.finish (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:9)
at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
at /Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:271:11
at _addModuleChain (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/node_modules/ngx-tel-input/ngx-tel-input.ngfactory.ts
148:12-17 "export 'ɵb' (imported as 'i1') was not found in 'ngx-tel-input'
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:65:15)
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:39:15)
at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:24)
at Compilation.finish (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:9)
at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
at /Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:271:11
at _addModuleChain (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/node_modules/ngx-tel-input/ngx-tel-input.ngfactory.ts
148:46-51 "export 'ɵb' (imported as 'i1') was not found in 'ngx-tel-input'
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:65:15)
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:39:15)
at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:24)
at Compilation.finish (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:9)
at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
at /Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:271:11
at _addModuleChain (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/node_modules/ngx-tel-input/ngx-tel-input.ngfactory.ts
152:46-51 "export 'ɵb' (imported as 'i1') was not found in 'ngx-tel-input'
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:65:15)
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:39:15)
at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:24)
at Compilation.finish (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:9)
at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
at /Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:271:11
at _addModuleChain (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:481:11)
at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:452:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

ERROR in ng:///Users/franke/projects/work/jsapp/node_modules/ngx-tel-input/ngx-tel-input.d.ts.ɵb.html (4,6): Property 'number' does not exist on type 'TelInputComponent'.
```

What's the problem and how i can solve it?

PS
My lib: https://github.com/LPgenerator/ngx-tel-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent was probably to export just what is needed, but you need to export everything from your `src/index.ts` file, including all the services, directives, and pipes.